Optimizing the code for find primes upto n using recursion
I had written a code for finding primes using recursion and this code needs some refining, I need somebody to help me in this case
#include<stdio.h>

int is_prime(int,int,int);
void generate_prime(int,int,int);

int main()
{
    int n,i=2,p=2;
    printf("Enter the limit: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n>=2)
    {
        is_prime(p,i,n);
        printf("\n");
    }
    else
        printf("Invalid input\n");
    return 0;
}
int is_prime(int p,int i,int n)
{
    if(p>2)
    {
        if(i<p)
        {
            if(p%i==0)
                is_prime(++p,2,n);
            is_prime(p,++i,n);
        }
    }
    else
        generate_prime(1,p,n);
}
void generate_prime(int c,int p,int n)
{
    if(p<=n)
        if(c)
        {
            printf(" %d",p);
            is_prime(++p,2,n);
        }
}

This was the code I wrote and by logic I found this program correct but somehow the code stops printing after 2, so I seek help here to debug my code and improve, if possible

This isn't a good use case for recursion. You'll blow the call stack after a few thousand calls. Try a sieve with iteration. Also, always fix compiler errors and warnings: a.cpp:33:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]. That's undefined behavior. Generally, functions should return values rather than print. Let the caller print if they want.

Thanks for the advice, sir. It was my task to do in such a way and I have solved my problem myself, thanks again.

Consider sharing the answer to help others with the same problem as you. I've rolled back your edit because answers go in the answer section, not the question section. The original problem needs to be preserved in the question so the answers make sense in context.

If you're using recursion, ++p is unnecessary. You're passing that by value, so just p + 1 works just as well.

Also, if (p <= n) if (c) { ... } is better written as if (p <= n && c) { ... }
